# getting text from facebook wall

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, facebook-wall

i'm looking for an elegant way to get the whole text on facebook wall - including the text diplayed when clicking "Older Posts" recursively - without adds and irrelavant data, including 
friend's posts, activities like "new friend", "in relationship" etc.

i prefer a way that doesn't involve dealing with facebook api, but if there is a covnvenient way to do this with the api i'll like to hear about it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is possible without FB's API, but trust me: don't!

There have been numerous examples of people getting kicked off of Facebook for exactly this. Web scraping is not allowed by their TOS, so the only legal way is through the API. This is also the most elegant way, in my opinion, since your script won't implode in case Facebook change their layout; API calls maintain backwards compatibility.

So my advice would be to dive into the API docs. They're pretty accessible.